# A club has $9$ women and $8$ men. Count the number of different committees of size $4$ with $3$ or $4$ women.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

1) *A club has 9 women and $8$ men. Count the number of different committees of size 4 with $3$ or $4$ women.*

How can I take in account for $3$ women and $1$ man? I have ${9 \choose 4}$ thus far.

Comment: Well, $\binom 94$ would be the case if all four committee members were women, which is one part of the question.  Now, what can you do if there are exactly $3$ women on the committee?

Comment: Count the number of committees with four women. Then count the number of committees with three women. Then add the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) For choose $3$ women you have ${9 \choose 3}$ possibilities and for choose $1$ man you have ${8 \choose 1}$, so the total is $${9 \choose 3}\cdot {8 \choose 1}$$

2) For choose $4$ women you have ${9 \choose 4}$ and  so the total is $${9 \choose 4}$$

The total is then:

$${9 \choose 3}\cdot {8 \choose 1}+{9 \choose 4}$$

Comment: My professor said all I was missing is 3 women 1 man??

Comment: @Arthur: yes, thanks

Comment: can you explain both parts please?

Comment: @RobertMiller: Is it clear?

Comment: Not clear, no. Can you explain each please? Your logic? Why would you account for 0 men?

Comment: @RobertMiller: Actually you don't need that because ${8 \choose 0}=1$. I took it off

Comment: These are all combinations, correct?

Comment: @RobertMiller: yes, they are! because the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:**

$3$ women and $1$ man

$${}_9 C_3 \times {}_8 C_1 = 672$$

**Case 2:**

$4$ women and $0$ men

$${}_9 C_4 \times {}_8 C_0= 126$$

> Total number  of possible  committees then is $672+126=798$